# Issues reading contents of http post from socket, only getting header

Tags: java, http, httpclient

server

```
 public void HandleConnection(Socket socket) {
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              String strLine;
              try {
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                  System.out.println (strLine);
                  }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

client

```
public void httpPostTest() {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.2:8080/");

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("test"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Any thoughts on this? This is all I get back, just the header:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Host: 192.168.0.2:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)




public String readLine(InputStream inputStream) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "ASCII");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String theString = writer.toString();
        return theString.trim();
    }
```

Comment: When you say it's all you 'get back', do you mean it's what you recieve at the server side? Not a response at the client side, presumably...

Comment: Also, if you use wireshark/tcpdump etc, what do you see? Is the client failing to send the body, or is the server failing to recieve it? I notice that the request has a `Content-Length: 4` header, which makes sense if your body is `test`, so the question is, is it transmitted across the network (in which case it's a server problem) or not (in which case it's the client).

Comment: Sorry, by get back what I ment to say was that on the server I am printing the received inputStream to console, and all that is being printed to console is the above header, the body is not. In this case, the body should be the 4 character string "test", and as you pointed out the content -length does match this string. When I change the string length, the content-length also matches. I guess my question is, on the server side I dont think i'm correctly processing this post request as I'm just seeing the header. I want to get the message body as well, the "test" string in this case. Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your server-side code - there is (should be) a blank line between the header and the body (in other words, the last header should be followed by two CRLF sequences instead of just one), and readLine will return an empty string for this line because it strips line termination characters, but it still shouldn't equal `null`. I really recommend you inspect the network traffic and a) make sure the body is actually being sent and b) check for other oddities. If the body is sent in a seperate packet it may cause the problem, but your `BufferedReader` should stop that.

Comment: Looking at the traffic with wireshark, I can clearly see the text data in the same packet as the header. I tried to use a different approach to read the inputStream on the server, this created a new problem (the client connection will hang) but it will print the message body. My bufferedReader approach seems to be the prefered method, so now I am trying to figure out why that doesn't work but this does:  (see below)

Comment: public String readLine(InputStream inputStream) {
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  try {
   IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "ASCII");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  String theString = writer.toString();
  return theString.trim();
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand after doing some reading, BufferedReader is a bad way to read inputStreams from http post. What I was experiencing was that the client making the post would hang and so what the connection handler thread on every post, when I would kill the client the server would stop hanging and I would see the message body. From what I gathered on the internet, the best way to read the input stream is to step through it byte by byte, and exit the loop after the sum of the bytes == the content-length value.

That said, I'm planning on using Apache HTTPCore instead to handle this as that seems like a better solution

Answer (score 0):

For whats worth, if someone comes here like me, here's what I wrote

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while(stream.read(b) > 0 && !socket.isInputShutdown()) {
    System.out.println(new String(b));
    b = null;
    b = new byte[1024];
}
```